# Use predicates.maude in Igor2.3 and how to get the result from Rewrite Result

Tags: haskell, maude-system

How to use predicates.maude? 
Is there any example about the usage of it

```
Maude> SETUP(PREDICATE) .
Warning: <standard input>, line 163: skipped unexpected token: SETUP
Warning: no loop state.
Warning: <standard input>, line 163: syntax error
```

It seems rewrite do the work of reducing too

How to get the result 7, I see that it is in iterations

```
RewriteResult {resultTerm = IterTerm {termSort = "NzNat", termOp = "s_", termChildren = [Term {termSort = "Zero", termOp = "0", termChildren = []}], iterations = 7}, rewriteStatistics = MaudeStatistics {totalRewrites = 1, realTime = 0, cpuTime = 0}}
```